# Cannot find symbol method findViewByInt

Tags: java, android

I have created a tabbed activity and wish that one of the Tabs will display the current time and date. I have already linked the fragments together however having some issues with displaying the time and date.

This is the error:

> Error:(34, 61) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

and also:

> Error:(31, 25) error: cannot find symbol method runOnUiThread()

This is the code;

```
package com.example.user.plannerv2;

import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class sub_page01 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Sub_page01";

    // private Button btnTEST;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01,container,false);

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                            public void run() {
                                TextView tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
                                long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy\nhh-mm-ss a");
                                String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                                tdate.setText(dateString);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();



        return view;
    }
```

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You are inside a fragment, you should use `view.findViewById( )` instead.

Replace: `TextView tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);`

To: `TextView tdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);`

Comment: Thank you, that fixes the issue regarding view.`findViewById()` however still the problem of `Error:(31, 25) error: cannot find symbol method runOnUiThread(<anonymous Runnable>)` stands.

Comment: in addition, `runOnUiThread` is an Activity method.

Comment: you can go `getActivity().ruinOnUiThread(...`

Comment: like @C0D3LIC1OU5 said, `runOnUiThread( )` is an Activity method, you can`t call it in your Fragment. use your Activity instead like the comment above.

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: you are calling  `runOnUiThread()` method, this method belongs to `Activity` class, your `Fragment` is not an `Activity`, so you cannot do that, but you can get your `Activity` inside your `Fragment` calling the `getActivity().runOnUiThread( )`

Answer (score 0):

For

> Error:(34, 61) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

In Fragment,we have to initialize our view like this,

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01,container,false);

    TextView tdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
return view;
```

For

> Error:(31, 25) error: cannot find symbol method runOnUiThread()

runOnUiThread() is Activity method so.In Fragment,Always put like this,

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                            public void run() {
                                TextView tdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                                long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy\nhh-mm-ss a");
                                String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                                tdate.setText(dateString);
                            }
                        });
```

It will fix the problem.